# Seurat Tutorial Help. I cannot get past this error message

Tags: r, seurat, tar.gz

I am doing this tutorial: https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html

I always get the error message listed at the end! I cannot get past this!

```r
library(dplyr)
```

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

```r
library(Seurat)
```

```r
Attaching SeuratObject
```

```r
library(patchwork)
# Load the PBMC dataset
pbmc.data <- Read10X(data.dir = "../data/pbmc3k/filtered_gene_bc_matrices/hg19/")
```

```r
Error in Read10X(data.dir = "../data/pbmc3k/filtered_gene_bc_matrices/hg19/") : 
  Directory provided does not exist
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the data and placed them into the right folder? See the first paragraph of the tutorial.